# Can the UK student loan company stop a graduate from moving abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, loans, student-loan, working-abroad

I'm just worried about hearing that a lot of people move to avoid repayments. I do not intend to not pay back the loan. I want to move to join my bf and then get married. I always have wanted to move even before uni and if I get a job which passes the threshold or if my wage is enough to pay back then I certainly would pay back my loan.

So can the loan company or govt stop someone from moving abroad? And restrict them to the UK?

Will be graduating in 2 yrs

I'm sorry if this question sounds stupid I am just a very neurotic type of person and I really want to get married and live with my bf hopefully after graduating and just don't want any problems.

I live in the UK and am British

Comment: What is your citizenship ? Many EU students run away without paying their loans and it happens quite frequently. It doesn't go on your credit report, so might not affect your credit score when taking credit later on(unless revealed in your application). But if you want to fly off, they will find you and make you pay.  http://www.independent.co.uk/student/student-life/9-common-myths-about-your-student-loan-8794151.html

Comment: God.... I never said I will not pay if I will earn over the threshold then I will pay if not then I won't. But can the student loan company restrict someone to the UK and prevent them from moving abroad.

Comment: My comment was questioning your motive. You say `if I will earn over the threshold then I will pay if not then I won't` which is primarily using the loophole and not pay the loan(easier if you move abroad), which might be struck off after 25/35 years. And it has been made a criminal offence and might screw up your credit rating too, so it is up to you.

Comment: Well no I am not using any loop hole. The reason I said that was because a lot of people move and don't pay. I have no intention to do that If I am able to pay as in if I am earning so much that allows me to pay back or if I am paying over the threshold then I would pay. As I don't know what I will earn I had to say if. If I am not earning enough then why should I pay how can I pay? There's nothing wrong with what I said. I HAVE ALWAYS DECIDED TO MOVE and I don't want uni to come in between especially when I am not leaving to escape the loan. My question was can they stop an individual moving.

Comment: And if I am not earning enough. Not just me if anyone is jobless or is not earning enough or is not over the threshold then how can they pay? Only when they are able to they will pay. That's what makes sense. If you have money that allows you to pay then you would if not then you would wait until you find a better job or get a higher wage. It's logical

Comment: Don't pile on me. I am only mentioning the questions you will be asked if they decide to follow up on you. If nothing happens then well and good.

Comment: What questions would they ask? Why have you moved? Well it's my life and its up to me where I live I moved so I can make my own life

Comment: You do have a loan right, right ? Willn't the lender be worried about the money lent and how to recover it ? Are you assuming people lending money are out to do charity ?

Comment: Omg I swear down. OF COURSE I KNOW THEY WOULD WANT TO KNOW ABOUT THE MONEY. You send an overseas assessment and every year you inform them of you're circumstances which I plan on doing I NEVER said I'm gonna run off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fellow student here! Okay, I don't have enough rep to ask you a question otherwise I would check which year you started uni (2 years left could be on anything from a 3 year course to a 5 year sandwich with integrated masters and a retake year) and which UK country you were in, as the repayment rules differ slightly depending on whether you were using Student Finance England&Wales/NI/Scotland.

However assuming you started after September 2012 and were in England/Wales i.e. [plan 2](http://www.studentloanrepayment.co.uk/portal/page?_pageid=93,6678715&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL), you would need to complete an [Overseas Income Assessment Form](http://www.studentloanrepayment.co.uk/portal/page?_pageid=93,6678804&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL) to let the repayment company know how much you're earning and calculate the equivalent repayment rate depending the earnings threshold for your destination country. It'd be up to you to let them know if your circumstances change, but there's no way they'd stop you from leaving the UK.

I think the other plans work in the same way but you can check your particular circumstance on the student loan repayment website [here](http://www.studentloanrepayment.co.uk/portal/page?_pageid=93,3866794&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL).

So in short, nope. You'll be fine!

Comment: Thank you! You're answer helped a lot. I have always wanted to move I decided even before uni years ago. So I just don't want uni to cause any problems. I understand a lot of people move to escape the loan but this is not my intension nor will it ever be. I just want to settle down in another country and pay back the loan when my income is over the threshold. I don't understand why people are questioning my motive suggesting that I won't pay. When it's nothing like that like if my wage is over the threshold i will pay if it's not I don't have to its written in the terms.